# lazyvim: change default settings

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm using lazyvim and I'm trying to change some default settings:

According to [documentation here](https://www.lazyvim.org/extras/lang/java#nvim-jdtls) seems that I'm able to change default `root_dir` detection.

It's not clear to how to chage that. I mean, By default, it's picking default `root_dir` detection from lspconfig.

Default lspconfig jdtls configuration is here and you can find [jdtls.lua lspconfig file here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/jdtls.lua#L79). You can also to see how to [`lsp_config` populate it on `default_config.root_dir` here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/jdtls.lua#L102).

I need to change to:

```
{'.git', 'mvnw', 'gradlew'}
```

Also, I've tried to change `nvim-jdtls` plugin settings using this code snipped on `_/lua/plugins/jdtls-change-root.lua`:

```lua
return {
  {
    "mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls",
    ---@type lspconfig.options.jdtls
    ---@diagnostic disable-next-line: missing-fields
    opts = {
      jdtls = function(opts)
        local root_dir = {{'.git', 'mvnw', 'gradlew'}}
        table.insert(opts.root_dir, root_dir)

        return opts
      end,
    },
  },
}
```

But something is wrong in that code.
Any ideas?